# Transit visa at Istanbul Airport, Turkey, during a Turkish Airlines arranged stopover?

Tags: visas, layovers, turkey, isl

Do I need a transit visa at Istanbul Airport to enter Istanbul for city sightseeing or hotel accommodation?. All services provided free by the Turkish Airline. I am Nigerian citizen and booked Turkish Airline flight to Nigeria with 12hours layover at Istanbul Airport.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes. If you want to enter inside Turkey, you'll definitely need a visa prior to your entry** i.e. visa on arrival is not applicable (phased out).

The situation with the Turkish visa for Nigerian nationals is a little bit more complicated than one might expect.

The [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa) website reveals,

> Nigeria: Ordinary and official passport holders are required to have
>   visa to enter Turkey. These passport holders with a valid Schengen or
>   OECD member's visa or residence permit may get their one month period
>   single entry e-Visas via the website [www.evisa.gov.tr](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/).

So the rules states that you are **applicable for a conditional one-month electronic visa** (only for tourism or commerce) and this visa is the one which you will need in order to enter Istanbul for tourism purposes. A transit visa is only for air-side transit and is not applicable here.

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Turkey#Conditional_e-Visa) also states,

> - all except citizens of Afghanistan, Bangladesh, China, Egypt, India,
>     Iraq, Mexico, Moldova, Pakistan and Taiwan must hold a round-trip
>     ticket to Istanbul Ataturk Airport with Turkish Airlines.
> - must hold a hotel reservation and adequate financial means (US$ 50 per day).

This I believe will not be an issue in your case since I analyze this to be a requirement for a proof of onward travel. Since you are already in transit to Nigeria, **you have this requirement fulfilled**. The hotel reservation and financial means I also believe shouldn't be an issue.

This leaves the only real issue i.e. you have to have either a **valid Schengen or [OECD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organisation_for_Economic_Co-operation_and_Development#Current_members) member's visa or residence permit**. If you do have a visa from one of these countries, by all means go ahead and apply for the electronic visa in the link I provided earlier. Otherwise, you will have to visit the Turkish Embassy or Consulate in order to get a visa.

**In both cases, you must ensure that you have a visa prior to your entry inside Turkey.**

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you want to leave the airport.

However you can transit through the airport without a visa.

The Turkish Ministry of Foreign Affairs [says](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa)

> Question: I will be flying to Europe. I know that our aircraft will
>   land in İstanbul. I am not planning to leave the transit lounge. Do I
>   need to get transit visa?
>
> Answer: If you will not leave the transit lounge at the airport you
>   are not required to have transit visa. Otherwise, you have to make
>   visa application to the nearest Turkish Representation. Contact
>   information of the said missions can be reached through www.mfa.gov.tr
>   (Ministry/Turkish Representations).

On the Turkish Airline Website it is also [clearly marked that](http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/travel-information/baggage/transit-transfer-passenger-procedures)

> International transfer passengers continuing to a foreign destination
>   with Turkish Airlines
>
> Passengers disembark with only their cabin baggage and proceed
>   directly to the boarding gates **without any flight or passport
>   procedures**.

(emphasis mine).

The airport's website also [says](http://www.ataturkairport.com/en-EN/preflight/Pages/Transfer.aspx)

> Transfer Passengers:(International Transfer Passengers With An
>   International Connection Flight) A boarding card is issued for the
>   passenger (if not issued in the country of origin) at the transit desk
>   of the relevant handling company on the Arrivals floor. **The passenger
>   does not go through passport control**.
>   (again emphasis mine).

Comment: The asker wants to leave the airport, so this answer doesn't apply.