# Does my husband need a visa for a layover in Turkey?

Tags: visas, layovers, turkey, nigerian-citizens

My husband is a national citizen of Nigeria. He has a 5 year permanent permit to live in Lithuania. We are planning to fly to Nigeria through Istanbul and the time between flights is more than 15 hours. We would get a hotel from Turkish airlines. Does my husband need a visa while in Turkey?

Comment: Maybe you could go through this post http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34236/transit-visa-at-istanbul-airport-turkey-during-a-turkish-airlines-arranged-sto . Similar to what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your husband would need a visa if he wants to exit the transit area. As a Nigerian citizen holding a valid Schengen resident permit, he is eligible to apply for one month e-Visa via the website www.evisa.gov.tr

> Nigeria: Ordinary, official/service passport holders are required to
>   have visa to enter Turkey. These passport holders with a valid
>   Schengen members or USA, UK, Ireland visa or residence permit may get
>   their single entry e-Visas valid for one month e-Visas via the website
>   www.evisa.gov.tr, provided that they meet certain conditions.

Source: http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa